# Keep defs in a separate file

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy

I have several defs in my main build.gradle file. Is it possible to move them into a separate file, and then just reference them?
Something like this (don't mind the syntax):

foobar.gradle

```
def foo = "foo"
def bar = "bar"
def baz = "baz"
```

main.gradle

```
println $foo
println $bar
println $baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

In foobar.gradle, set up the defs like this:

```
ext.foo = "foo"
ext.bar = "bar"
ext.baz = "baz"
```

Then in main.gradle, make sure to include this line:

```
apply from: 'foobar.gradle'
```

Now variables can be used as freely as if they are part of the main.gradle file.